# Can't filter by genre

Tags: java, android, list, filter

I have a hardcoded list of movies and I want to filter them by their genre (which is a string), however only the All filter works as of now and for the other genres the result is the same as for the All filter. Can anyone help me out

class HomePresenter:

```
public class HomePresenter {

List<Film> filmList = Repository.getHardcodedList();


public List<Film> filterByGenre(String genre){
    if (genre.equals("All"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Drama"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Adventure"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Animation"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Horror"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Comedy"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Romance"))
        return filmList;
    else if (genre.equals("Documentary"))
        return filmList;


    List<Film> filteredFilmList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Film f : filmList){

        if(f.getGenre().equals(genre)){

            filteredFilmList.add(f);
        }
    }

    return filteredFilmList;
}
```

Class Repository:

```
     public class Repository {
        static List<Film> filmList = new ArrayList<>();
        static List<Reservation> reservationList = new ArrayList<>();
        public static List<Film> favoriteList = new ArrayList<>();
        private static HashMap<String, HashMap<Time, List<Boolean>>> program;
        static List<Boolean> cinemaPlaces;
    
        public static List<Film> getHardcodedList() {
       

 List<Film> filmList = Arrays.asList(
            new Film("Despicable Me", "Animation", "better. ", 7.7, R.mipmap.despicable),
            new Film("The Martian", "Adventure", "alive. ", 8.0, R.mipmap.martian),
            new Film("Ted", "Comedy", "Lori. ", 6.9, R.mipmap.ted),
            new Film("Alita", "Adventure", "is. ", 7.6, R.mipmap.alita),
            new Film("Girl", "Drama", "ballerina. ", 7.2, R.mipmap.girl),
            new Film("A Star Is Born", "Romance", "spiral. ", 7.9, R.mipmap.star),
    );
        return filmList;
    }
```

Update with the spinner that I use for when choosing a genre of the movie:

HomeFragment:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getContext(),
                R.array.genres_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedGenre = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                List<Film> filteredFilmlist = homeActivityPresenter.filterByGenre(selectedGenre);
                final FilmAdapter adapter = new FilmAdapter(pointerSaver);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setFilmlist(filteredFilmlist);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
        });
```

Comment: You don't need the if statement.  That's the problem.

Comment: Then what can I use instead?

Comment: you're returning in every true branch of your if statements, so the code after is not being executed, you probably only want to return the filmList if the genre is ALL, for everything else just continue with the methods execution to hit your filter logic

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a stream?

```
List<Film> result = filmList.stream().filter(f -> genre.equals("All") || f.getGenre().equals(genre)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion but it returns the movies only for All category again, it does't work for other genres. I have updated the code above to include the snippet of the spinner that I also use in the fragment in case it helps.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of the getGenre() method in Film?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public List<Film> filterByGenre(String genre){
if (genre.equals("All"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Drama"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Adventure"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Animation"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Horror"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Comedy"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Romance"))
    return filmList;
else if (genre.equals("Documentary"))
    return filmList;


List<Film> filteredFilmList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Film f : filmList){

    if(f.getGenre().equals(genre)){

        filteredFilmList.add(f);
    }
}

return filteredFilmList;}
```

to

```
public List<Film> filterByGenre(String genre){
if (genre.equals("All")) {
    return filmList;
}


List<Film> filteredFilmList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Film f : filmList){

    if(f.getGenre().equals(genre)){

        filteredFilmList.add(f);
    }
}

return filteredFilmList;
}
```

you can clean this up further by creating an enumeration for the genre, rather than using magic strings, and if you are using Java 8+ then you can utilise Streams to create a filtered version of the filmList
i.e.
`return filmList.stream().filter(film -> genre.equals(film.getGenre())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion but it returns the movies only for All category again, it does't work for other genres. I have updated the code above to include the snippet of the spinner that I also use in the fragment in case it helps.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see whether the correct value is being passed into filterByGenre?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the same `List` with every genre comparison in the `if` statements.

Change to this:

```
List<Film> filmList = Repository.getHardcodedList();


public List<Film> filterByGenre(String genre){
    if (genre.equals("All"))
        return filmList;


    List<Film> filteredFilmList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Film f : filmList){

        if(f.getGenre().equals(genre)){

            filteredFilmList.add(f);
        }
    }

    return filteredFilmList;
}
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion but it returns the movies only for All category again, it does't work for other genres. I have updated the code above to include the snippet of the spinner that I also use in the fragment in case it helps.

Comment: Try 'parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();'

Comment: It sadly didn't fix it

Comment: Use 'String selectedGenre = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();'

Comment: I used it but it gives me the same results.